# Access Database over a network without actually sharing it

Tags: wpf, network-programming, ms-access-2010, multi-user

So here's the deal. I have a WPF application which stores all the data into MS Access Database. But it is supposed to be a multi-user based application.

**What I want:**
The application exe to run from each user node and get stored in the database present at a particular user's drive/location.

**What I have Tried:**
I put my application and access db file in a shared folder, and everything works fine. But I don't want my users to be able to copy the database. And according to what I researched and found, if I put any file on a shared location there's no way I can prevent anyone from copying it.

Considering the fact that I have negligible knowledge of Networking. I would like you to help me out with what I should search for, or the things that I should learn. Or if you could just provide the solution. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

This is what I imagine it should be like:

[image: This is what imagine it should be like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not possible.

An Access database is just a file. Anyone with read access to that file, has, well, read access to that file, which allows them to copy it.

You can try to obfuscate the file location, but a tech savvy user will always be able to download the database.

You're looking for a client-server RDBMS. There are tons available (MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, etc.). In fact, it's much more common than databases like Access.

Alternatively, you can develop your own server that reads and writes to the database and passes data to the nodes and disallow nodes to directly access the database, but this is very much nontrivial and Access is not supported for server use.